# If-statement in a stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Is it possible to use an if statement conidition in my map below?

```
public Map<LocalDate, Double> avarageTemperatures(LocalDate dateFrom, LocalDate dateTo) {

    Map<LocalDate, Double> tempAverage = Data.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Weather::getDateTime,
                    Collectors.averagingDouble(Weather::getTemp)));

    System.out.println("average: " + tempAverage);
    return tempAverage;
}
```

I want to only return the dates and tempAverage for dates between `datefrom` and `dateTo`, which is user input. So I would like to implement an if-statement like

```
for (Weather weather : Data){
    if(!weather.getDateTime().isAfter(dateTo) && !weather.getDateTime().isBefore(dateFrom)){}
}
```

where `weatherData` is an ArrayList containing dates and temperatures. My weather class:

```
public class Weather {
    private LocalDate dateTime;
    private LocalTime time;
    private double temperature;
    private String tag;
    //setter, getter, constructor 
}
```

The dates are of the form 1946-01-15, and temperature of the form -0.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)):

```
weatherData.stream().filter(weather -> !weather.getDateTime().isAfter(dateTo) &&
                                    !weather.getDateTime().isBefore(dateFrom))...
```